# Rebase without force push

Tags: git, github

I recently submitted a PR. My changes were made in a development branch. While my PR was being reviewed, some changes were made to the main branch. One of the reviewers asked me to update my branch. I pulled changes from the main branch, rebased my development branch, then force pushed. This caused issues with my pull request, which no longer shows commit history.

How should I have updated my branch without causing issues for existing pull requests?

Comment: Rebase rewrites history, so after a rebase the commits will be different.  But the history they show will be largely the same unless you squash them together.  It shouldn't really cause any issues with a pull request either way.  There is no way to rebase without rewriting history, but you could have merged `main` into your branch instead of rebasing.

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer shows commit history"? If you were 5 commits ahead of main before the rebase, then you should be 5 commits ahead of main after the rebase as well, unless you skipped or squashed some commits. Of course you can't see that the 5 commits were originally based on a different commit - that's what rebase does: It rewrites the git history.

Comment: Are you saying there are no commits in the PR now? That should only happen if the tip of your branch is reachable by `main`.

Comment: Rebasing and force pushing is a perfectly fine workflow. Doing that in itself probably didn't cause your problem: "This caused issues with my pull request, which no longer shows commit history." Maybe something went wrong during the rebase, or maybe you had conflicts and never completed the rebase, or, maybe the changes in your commits on your branch were already merged into `main` from another PR. All of these reasons could lead to your commits no longer appearing in the PR.

Comment: @TTT I believe it removes the "viewed" status for reviewers even when the file has not changed. It also marks all requested changes as "outdated" and moves all commits to the end of the conversation as their timestamps are updated to the time of the rebase. There were no conflicts as my changes are isolated to their own directory.

Comment: I think you need to update your question, because "no longer shows commit history" doesn't sound like what you just said in the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are [rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) your branch then it will modify your commit history. While rebasing you should choose which commits to pick and which to squash if you want to keep some commits in the history. The whole point is to combine a series of commits to a new base commit.

You could have just pushed the merge commit after pulling from your main branch and your commit history would remain same with just an extra [merge commit](https://linuxhint.com/what-exactly-is-a-merge-commit-in-git/) in the end.